# How to include Bootstrap 5 JS file (bootstrap.bundle.js) to laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, laravel-8, bootstrap-5, popper.js

I've installed Bootstrap v5.1.0 to my Laravel 8 project using npm. How do I include **bootstrap.bundle.js** at my **public/app.js**?

I have installed popperjs and added this code to my *resources/js/bootstrap.js*

```
try {
        window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core');

        require('bootstrap');
    } catch (e) {
}
```

**My webpack.mix.js code:**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

And I have added CSS & JS on my template like this:

```
{{-- Styles --}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">

{{-- Script --}}
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

The public/js.app.js (generated from mix) has a lot of codes (see picture below), But still bootstrap JS codes(ex: Popovers) not working.

[image: Bootstrap.bundle.js not working]

How can I properly include Bootstrap JS files in my project?

Comment: Do you require your bootstrap.js in your app.js? What happens when you remove the try-catch block form bootstrap.js? Do you get any error?

Comment: Not an exact answer, but I'm sure the answer can be found under [Vite's minify](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference#minify-options) options which leads to the [Terser configuration page](https://terser.org/docs/api-reference#minify-options) where the best info is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. It was a silly mistake. Bootstrap 5 requires additional JavaScript code for popovers to work. I'm writing this answer for (if) anyone come here from googling. Here is the link of Popover codes. [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/popovers/)

And all the codes I found on *public/js.app.js* (generated from mix) was created on development environment (`npm run dev`). When I run `npm run prod` (Production) it get rids of these codes and also minifies the output.

Thank you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `import 'bootstrap'`

You can try
`import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'`